# Scala MergeSort

Tags: scala, mergesort

I am new to Scala and have to implement MergeSort.

The given prototype looks like this: `def mergeSort(split : List[Int] => (List[Int], List[Int]), as: List[Int]): List[Int]`

I don't ask you to implement MergeSort for me, I already know how to do it. My problem is with the method definition I am not allowed to change.

I don't know how to deal with `split : List[Int] => (List[Int], List[Int]), as: List[Int])`
It obviously means that it splits a given List into two, but how do I access the two resulting lists?

And if I try something like this:
`if (List.length < 2) List` I get the error: error: value length is not a member of object List

However, I have seen examples of MergeSort doing exactly that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints:

- `if (as.length < 2) { ... }`
- `val (lefts, rights) = split(as)`

Comment: Does that mean, that If I want to access the entire list, I just have to call it as?

Comment: you have two arguments there: a split function (split) and the entire list (as)

Comment: The split in the method head: What does it do? Are there two list parameters that are combined into one or is there one list parameter that is split in two?

Comment: So this denotes a function? split : List[Int] => (List[Int], List[Int])

Comment: this denotes a function that takes a list and returns a tuple consisting of two lists

Comment: Would you be so kind as to show me an example of how to call the method? That's the last thing I have a problem with.